# Session is closed in POST endpoint (reactive, mutiny, quarkus, panache)

Tags: reactive, quarkus-panache

I'm using reactive panache with resteasy in a quarkus project and I want to implement a post endpoint hat receives a pojo, returns a 202 (accepted) immediately and stores the pojo in the background.
I got it to work based on the provided quarkus [example](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-reactive):

```
@POST
public Uni<Response> create(Fruit fruit) {
    return Panache.<Fruit>withTransaction(fruit::persist)
            .onItem().transform(inserted -> Response.created(URI.create("/fruits/" + inserted.id)).build());
}
```

But this implementation waits for the persist call to finish. I want to achieve something like this:

```
@POST
public Uni<Response> createInBackround(Fruit fruit) {
    // Storing a fruit can take some time - Create a pipeline to store the fruit in the background
    Panache.<Fruit>withTransaction(fruit::persist)
       .subscribe().with(savedFruit -> LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Fruit saved successfully!"));
    // Return 202 response immediately to tell the client the request has been accepted
    return Uni.createFrom().item(Response.accepted().build());
}
```

The second code snippet results in an error that the session is closed:

> ERROR [io.qua.mut.run.MutinyInfrastructure] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-9) Mutiny had to drop the following exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: HR000060: Session is closed

Can anybody help me understand why this is happening?

Comment: While I'm digging deeper into this issue I realized what's causing the exception: the post call ends before the call to persist is executed, since this code runs on a different thread. Of course the session is gone after the call ended.

To make my question more precise:
How do I pass the session down to the executing thread? I thought this is handled by context propagation (https://quarkus.io/guides/context-propagation) automatically!?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using the `.onItem().call()` function.

As you said, the error is generated becouse your funciton

> `@POST public Uni<Response> createInBackround(Fruit fruit) {`

return an Uni, so it will clone before the `persist()` is executed completely.

As the [Mutiny Tutorial](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/1.7.0/tutorials/observing-events/#the-call-method) says: the `.call()` method

> is often used when you need to implement asynchronous side-effects, such as closing resources {...}
>
> {...} Mutiny does not dispatch the original event downstream until the Uni
> returned by the callback emits an item

So try to write something like this to make this work properly:

```
    @POST
public Uni<Response> createInBackround(Fruit fruit) {
   ...
   ...
    return Uni.createFrom().item(Response.accepted().build())
           .onItem().call(Panache.<Fruit>withTransaction(fruit::persist));
}
```

Mutiny Tutorial: https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/1.7.0/tutorials/observing-events/#the-call-method